# Two mixes rendering Black screen

Tags: rendering

Wanted to do a lyrics Video. So i connected an Image sequence and a movie Clip to a mix.
The outcoming Signal went into another mix, together with another Image sequence. 
However it renders only the Sound with a black Screen.

Can anyone tell me an answere? I do not want to do it all again in case the Data is screwed. Cause that Video includes 450 Images, all set up in Dope sheet..

[image: ][][image][image]

Comment: I don't see any preview in second sequnce, like it couldn't load image... If you will render only from first Mix, does output produce blackscreen?

Comment: Use the viewer node to troubleshoot the node chain. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132293/how-to-use-the-viewer-node/132300#132300

Comment: I added two screenshots. Referring to 1 or 2 mixes.. In that project (in the pictures)  it does not make any difference. But i started a new project and in this it does make a difference.

Comment: just figured out that it depends on the sequence you connect the mixes (and the image sequences) for my Backup.. But still i have the problem with Not rendering anything in my finished project. Seemingly There is no explanation. In node editor i can see it via backdrop etc. But f12 just Shows a transparent / black image

Comment: Try to disable *Sequencer* render in *Postprocess* settings

Comment: se: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24440/cycles-render-output-solid-black-images/24453#24453 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/blender-is-rendering-an-older-version-my-project

Comment: Yes it seems to work! Thank you serge!! Really really helped me !! I have no idea what that means, no idea what i did or why this box was checked